# could a race of sentient fungi exist?

Tags: science-based

recently, I had read another post on this website asking if plants could somehow gain sentience. I thought the idea was cool, so I took inspiration from it to try and create a society from another non-animal species, the mushroom. I have an idea of HOW they might survive as sentient creatures, but how could they become sentient? more importantly, how could they evolve:

- the ability to move around
- the ability to use tools
- the ability to communicate
- the ability to have complex thought processes?

Comment: *Sentient* meaning "able to perceive the world"? Or do you mean *sapient* meaning "intelligent" and "self-aware". Humans, scientifically called Homo **Sapiens**, are *sapient*, while a frog or even a tape worm are sentient.

Comment: Perhaps Warhammer will have some inspiring ideas for you. The Orcs are, after all, a fungi. In general though, plants and fungi are considered to lack the tissue types for multicellular locomotion.

Comment: You may want to google "Slime Mold". While not formerly classified as fungi, they express astonishing amounts of "sentinent behaviour"

Answer (score 5):

No.

An intelligent, mushroom-looking creature: sure.  But I don't think we'd consider it a fungus.

If you start with a fungus and start adding features until it meets your requirements, it will start to break the rules of our definition of fungus.  The primary characteristic of fungus is they have chitin in their cell walls.  That's not incompatible with your goals, but if a scientist found a walking, talking goomba-looking thing with chitinous cell walls, they would say, "How weird is it that this animals has fungus-like cellular biology."  Eventually, I think we'd create a new Kingdom for the weird creature.  Something that's neither an animal nor a fungus.

Movement requires muscles.  Thought requires neurons.  There's no reason they need to be similar to ours, but they definitely need more cellular differentiation than exists in what we know as fungus.  Having so many different tissue types would disqualify them from being fungus.

Fungus move only by growth (and by spreading spores).  Proper locomotion disqualifies it from being a fungus.

In a strict taxonomic sense, I really don't think what you want is possible within our current definition of fungus.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, until fairly recently, slime molds could have been held up as a counterexample to your claim that fungi are incapable of locomotion. Even in the "supercell" phase, they are capable of very slow amoeba-like movement. However, they have recently been reclassified and are no longer considered fungi (pretty much for the reasons you describe).

Comment: Is it possible that mushroom fruit (take that classical toadstool we’re familiar with) could end up, by chance, displaying traits that we could ‘confuse’ with being what is described above? Like, there are many mushrooms that have bioluminescence; perhaps a system could evolve where receptors on a mushroom react to other mushrooms and modify their displays accordingly resulting in what we might believe to be commutation. Also you have slime-molds’ incredible knack for resource distribution that rivals think-tanks of human engineers. And of course the dreaded Cordyceps (the Flood)...

Comment: ...given all that I’m sure there is room to be inventive with the mycelium in your fictional ecology and perhaps another sentient species can find a practical and original use in them. You just need to justify their existence and show them to play a role in the ecology rather than simply crowbarring them in.